# List generated in constructor not calling event handler

Tags: reactjs

I am generating a list on elements inside the constructor and rendering it inside render function. I am properly binding `this` to the event handler, but still not able to call the event handler. I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/naeemshaikh27/pen/XoXOyM)

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App boxes="9" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Box from './Box';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.play = this.click.bind(this);
    this.boxes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < props.boxes; i++) {
      this.boxes.push(<Box key={i} onClick={this.play} />);
    }
  }
  click() {
    console.log('called click');
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="App">{this.boxes}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

However it works fine if I bind the onClick function inside the render function, or even when I call the `onClick` prop inside Box.js

Box.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Box.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="box">{this.props.display}</div>;
    // return (
    // <div onClick={this.props.onClick} className="box">
   //   {this.props.display}
   // </div>
   // );  -- this helps me trigger the event handler on App component

  }
}

export default App;
```

Can you help me add the event handler without specifying the onclick handler twice i.e on both App component and Box component

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me add the event handler without specifying the onclick
>   handler twice i.e on both App component and Box component

You have to specify it twice, once to *give* the function to the Box component, and second time, to let the Box component *decide* when to call that function; this is what you do in your second example, which is commented out.

Otherwise, how do you imagine it specifying it only once?

Comment: I thought, it would call the event handler like other components do, for above example: `<div onClick={this.play} className="App">{this.boxes}</div>;` this works

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Sorry I don't understand the question

Comment: sorry,  I was thinking like if I am creating a Box component from App component then i can pass an event handler from parent App without specifying it in the child Box component like twice..

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Sorry I have hard time understanding what you are interested in, maybe update the question, and make it more concrete. Like I said you have to give function to Box component, and inside Box component you must decide when to call that function, right?

Comment: yes, But I understand your answer and I think you are right, it has to be controlled within child component..  thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to strore the boxes in the state and refer the `onClick` within the render method, not in constructor. 
You can completely get rid of constructor btw simply using arrow functions as methods.

```js
const Box = ({onClick, label}) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>{label}</div>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    boxes: [
      {id: 1, label: 'Box label 1'},
      {id: 2, label: 'Box label 2'},
    ]
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('box click');
  }
  
  render() {
    const { boxes } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {boxes.map(box => (
          <Box key={box.id} label={box.label} onClick={this.handleClick} />))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```